# For Loop only adds same object every time instead of different object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am writing a for loop that is iterating over an array which contains different lines in a text document.

Each iteration I am trying to pull certain parts of each of the text data lines and add them to an object, namely localinoData.

At the end of each iteration I am trying to add the localinoData object (with each object property set to a new one) to a new array.

When just adding the string found in each line the to data array (localinoDataObjArray) I get different values for each of the array. However when I now change the localinoData object properties on each iterations and try to append that changed object to the array, i get the same object in all of the array positions, e.g when I

alert(localinoDataObjArray[x].X_COORD);

for all values of x, the X_COORD is the same.

```
function GetlocalinoDataFromFile(localinoDataFile){
    var localinoDataObjArray = new Array();
    var localinoData = {
        time: null,
        tagID: null,
        X_COORD: null,
        Y_COORD: null,
        Z_COORD: null,
    };

    var allData = localinoDataFile.responseText;
    var arrayOfDataLines = allData.split('\n');

    // for each iteration, get the tagID, and the co-ords(seperate) and then 
    // create a localinoData object and add to array
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfDataLines.length; i++) {    

        if (/tag: [0-9]{22}/.test(arrayOfDataLines[i])) {
         var tagID = /tag: [0-9]{22}/.exec(arrayOfDataLines[i]);
         localinoData.tagID = tagID;

        }

        if (/[0-9]+.[0-9]{3}, [0-9]+.[0-9]{3}, [0-9].[0-9]{3}/.test(arrayOfDataLines[i])) {               
            XYZ_COORDS = /[0-9]+.[0-9]{3}, [0-9]+.[0-9]{3}, [0-9].[0-9]{3}/.exec(arrayOfDataLines[i]);   
            temp = XYZ_COORDS.toString();
            temp2 = temp.split(', ');
            // Here I am changing the object to new values each loop
            localinoData.X_COORD = temp2[0];
            localinoData.Y_COORD = temp2[1];
            localinoData.Z_COORD = temp2[2];

        }
        // Here I am appending the newly changed object to my array
        // however the same object is being added every time 
        // (which corresponds to the last line in the text document)
        localinoDataObjArray.push(localinoData);
    }  
     // the object values for localinoDataObjArray[0] 
     // and localinoDataObjArray[50] are the exact same
     alert(localinoDataObjArray[20].X_COORD);
}
```

I expect all of the array values to be different corresponding to the different lines in the text document. However all of the array values are the same (which equal the expected result of iteration over the last line in the text document).

I am very confused as when i = 0, it should be adding an object that has the values of the first line in my text document, however it shows the values i would expect from the last line in the document.

This is very strange to me and seems like a looping problem? I am very confused and would appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: Perhaps you should reinitialize your `locationData` inside of the loop on every iteration. You are adding/referencing same object each time and only owerwrite it's properties.

Comment: Ah yes I see, that has worked thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all references to the same object which you keep overwriting.
Try and make a fresh instance of localinoData in every iteration of your for loop.

```
function GetlocalinoDataFromFile(localinoDataFile){
    var localinoDataObjArray = new Array();

    var allData = localinoDataFile.responseText;
    var arrayOfDataLines = allData.split('\n');

    // alert(arrayOfDataLines[4]);

    // for each iteration, get the tagID, and the co-ords(seperate) and then create a localinoData object and add to array
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfDataLines.length; i++) { 
        var localinoData = {
            time: null,
            tagID: null,
            X_COORD: null,
            Y_COORD: null,
            Z_COORD: null,
        };   

        if (/tag: [0-9]{22}/.test(arrayOfDataLines[i])) {
         var tagID = /tag: [0-9]{22}/.exec(arrayOfDataLines[i]);
         localinoData.tagID = tagID;

        }

        if (/[0-9]+.[0-9]{3}, [0-9]+.[0-9]{3}, [0-9].[0-9]{3}/.test(arrayOfDataLines[i])) {               
            XYZ_COORDS = /[0-9]+.[0-9]{3}, [0-9]+.[0-9]{3}, [0-9].[0-9]{3}/.exec(arrayOfDataLines[i]);   
            temp = XYZ_COORDS.toString();
            temp2 = temp.split(', ');
            localinoData.X_COORD = temp2[0];
            localinoData.Y_COORD = temp2[1];
            localinoData.Z_COORD = temp2[2];
    }

    localinoDataObjArray.push(localinoData);
}  
 alert(localinoDataObjArray[20].X_COORD);
```

}